# How to define unequal allocation of groups in blockrand() in R

Tags: r, random, block, allocation

I want to design a randomized clinical trial using R v.4.0.3 and blockrand package.
The following is my code:

```
library(blockrand)
library(writexl)
library(openxlsx)

set.seed(101)
Mos1<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='XX-Y1')
set.seed(10)
Mos2<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='XX-Y2')
set.seed(5)
Mos3<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='XX-Y3')
set.seed(70)
Mos4<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='NONXX-Y1')
set.seed(43)
Mos5<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='NONXX-Y2')
set.seed(87)
Mos6<-blockrand(n=295, id.prefix= 'Mos -', block.prefix='B', block.sizes =1:2, stratum='NONXX-Y3')

dataset_names <- list('XX-Y1' = Mos1, 'XX-Y2' = Mos2,
                      'XX-Y3' = Mos3, 'NONXX-Y1' = Mos4,
                      'NONXX-Y2' = Mos5,'NONXX-Y3' = Mos6)
```

As you see the block.size in the function is defined as "1:2", and since the number of treatment groups is 2 (it is not written, it is default), this code produces the actual block sizes of 2 and 4 (it is multiplied).
But I want the produced block sizes to be 3 and 6, while the number of groups be still 2. This means that for example in a block of 3, we will have two group A and one group B (total=3).
But I could not find out how this will work out, as when I set the "block.size=3:1.5", the produced block sizes are 6 and 4. And it never goes to 6 and 3.
Could anybody can help?

Comment: Hi Oscar. Never forget to include the language. The other tags don't have that many followers so otherwise you will not appear in their filters (if you're missing highlighting of source code then this is a reminder to put in the language tag).

Answer (score 0):

one approach:

```
library(blockrand)
```

create a lookup vector associating `stratum` names with names for the block items to be generated:

```
stratum_lookup <- setNames(
  c(paste0('XX-Y', 1:3), paste0('NONXX-Y', 1:3)),
  paste0('Mos', 1:6)
)

## > stratum_lookup
##       Mos1       Mos2       Mos3       Mos4       Mos5       Mos6 
##    "XX-Y1"    "XX-Y2"    "XX-Y3" "NONXX-Y1" "NONXX-Y2" "NONXX-Y3"
```

- `Map` the future item names to blocks created to your specifications:

```
block_collection <- 
  names(stratum_lookup) |>
  Map(f = \(object_name){blockrand(n = 295, 
                                   num.levels = 2, 
                                   block.sizes = c(3, 6), ## (1)
                                   block.prefix = 'B',
                                   id.prefix = 'Mos-',
                                   stratum = stratum_lookup[object_name] ## (2)
                                  )
  })
```

1. use a vector of block sizes, not a continuous range (as `3:6` would return)
2. look up the stratum label for the item name

`block_collection` is a list of random block designs. Pick any of the list items like this:

```
block_collection[['Mos1']]

## > block_collection[['Mos1']]
##        id stratum block.id block.size treatment
## 1  Mos-01   XX-Y1       B1         12         B
## 2  Mos-02   XX-Y1       B1         12         B
## 3  Mos-03   XX-Y1       B1         12         A
## 4  Mos-04   XX-Y1       B1         12         A
## 5  Mos-05   XX-Y1       B1         12         A
## ...
```

You can move the list items as separate objects to your workspace like so:

```
list2env(block_collection)
```

However, this will only clutter your workspace w/o apparent benefit. To e.g., export each block as a spreadsheet, wrap the necessary statements in a `Map` as above:

```
library(rio) ## conveniently dispatches to various export libraries by file extension

names(block_collection) |>
  Map(f = \(block_name) block_collection[[block_name]] |>
                        export(file = sprintf('%s.xlsx', block_name))
      )
```